# Jain SIP in multi-thread environment

Tags: jain-sip

It's not clear how to use jain SIP stack in mutli-thread environment. I need to create multiple SIP sessions from different threads, e.g each client should be proceeded in its own transaction. Below is few options:

- Use single `SipProvider` for receiving and sending SIP requests and do multiplexing on application side. `SipProvider` is not thread-safe, hence sending requests requires proper locking.
- Create new `SipProvider` and new `ListeningPoint` for each client. This is how it works for me now. However, I don't really like it. And it's not clear, whther SipStack threadsafe or not
- Create new instance of `SipStack` for every client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been a long time since I thought about JAIN-SIP (or even SIP for that matter or even Java) but here goes:

1. Set the re-entrant listener flag when you create the stack. (look up the javadocs). Specify a thread pool size. When a sip request or response comes along, the stack may potentially create a new thread for you and invoke your listener.
2. Your critical section is the SipListener implementation. You should not block for ever in it - otherwise new inbound requests and responses will not be routed to the sip listener for the transaction that is being processed at the time you blocked.

Hope that answers your question. Happy hacking.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you ue SIP Servlets, it lets you focus on your application logic and handles those details for you ?
See http://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/

Comment: Why don't you advice me to use C++ or Scala instead of Java ? It should let me focus on my application logic

Comment: Well JAIN SIP is Java, so I assumed you wanted to go with a Java Based solution, hence my redirection to SIP Servlets which is higher abstraction over JAIN SIP. What application are you trying to build, I could point to a couple of examples to help you get started faster

Comment: Unfortunately the SIP Servlet stack mentioned is now GNU Affero so unusable.